# Optimizing if-elif expressions in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I'm trying to optimize my code by using dictionaries instead of if-elif statements.

I've read that you can optimize code by using dictionaries instead of if-elif statements, but I don't know how to do that. I'd like to use the logical expressions below somehow in the dictionary. (The code iterates through a and b)

```
def e_ha(n, t, a, b, E): 
    if a == b: 
        return 6
    elif (a%n == 0, a != n**2, b == a + 1) == (True, True, True):
        return 0 
    elif ((a-1)%n == 0, (a-1) != n**2, b == a - 1) == (True, True, True):
        return 0
    elif (a%n == 0, b == a-(n-1)) == (True, True):
        return 1
    elif (b%n == 0, a == b-(n-1)) == (True, True):
        return 1 
    elif abs(a-b) == 1:
        return 1
    elif abs(a-b) == n:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: `elif (a%n == 0, a != n**2, b == a + 1) == (True, True, True)` oy... what did `and` ever do to offend you?

Comment: I don't think this is a case where a dictionary can help you.

Comment: Would using `and` be better? I'm not very familiar with what works better for that kind of thing.

Comment: Certainly more readable: `elif (a % n == 0) and (a != n ** 2) and (b == a + 1)`. Even better would be to (1) use sensible variable names and (2) name those conditions sensibly. For example instead of `if a % n == 0` you might have something like `total_multiple_of_group = total % group_size == 0` and then `if total_multiple_of_group and total_not_group_squared and... `

Comment: What are the input ranges of `a` and `b`?

Comment: They both range from 1 to n**2

Comment: Are there any other constraints for `a` and `b` (e.g., `a - b` is bounded)?

Comment: By "optimize", do you want to achieve the best performance or do you just want to simplify the logic of the code?

Comment: The best performance. I'd like to make the whole thing go faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One naive approach to achieve the best performance is to build a big table storing the results for all possible `(a, b)` pairs. However, this could consume lots of memory and becomes inpractical for large `n`s.

Here is how the code can be optimized using a normal approach, as explained in the following step-by-step.

**1. Using Explicit `and` for Logical Expressions**

As suggested in the comments, this is much more readable and also more efficient because of the [short circuiting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/short-circuiting-techniques-python/) behavior of `and`. *This change alone reduces the runtime by 60%* in my tests.

**2. Remove Redundant Conditions**

Since both `a` and `b` range from `1` to `n**2`, if `a == n**2`, then `b == a + 1` can never be fulfilled. Therefore the `a != n**2` check in the condition `a%n == 0 and a != n**2 and b == a + 1` is redundant. The same applies to the third condition. Eliminating them simplifies these conditions to:

```
...
elif a % n == 0 and b == a + 1:
elif (a - 1) % n == 0 and b == a - 1:
...
```

**3. Avoid Repeated Computations in Conditions**

Note that the above-improved conditions 
`a % n == 0 and b == a + 1` and `(a - 1) % n == 0 and b == a - 1` are special cases of `abs(a - b) == 1`. Therefore these conditions can be rewritten using nested `if-else` as follows.

```
if abs(a - b) == 1:
   if a % n == 0 and b > a: return 0
   elif b % n == 0 and a > b: return 0  # a - 1 equals to b here so it is replaced to save one computation
   else return 1
```

Also note that the value `abs(a - b)` is related to all the conditions. Therefore it can be computed before all conditions are checked. With this change, the code becomes

```
d = abs(a - b)
if d == 0: return 6
elif d == 1:
   if a % n == 0 and b > a: return 0
   elif b % n == 0 and a > b: return 0
   else return 1
elif d == n - 1:
   if a % n == 0 and a > b: return 1
   elif b % n == 0 and b > a: return 1
   else return 0
elif d == n: return 1
else: return 0
```

**4. Simplify Logic**

For example, the first nested `if-else` above can be simplified to

```
if min(a, b) % n == 0: return 0
else return 1
```

A more compact syntax is:

```
return 1 if min(a, b) % n == 0 else 0
```

**5. Apply Python-specific Optimizations**

In Python, the number `0` is regarded as having a falsy value. So for numbers `if d != 0:` and `if d == 0:` are equivalent to `if d:` and `if not d:` respectively. The latter is a bit faster. Applying this change results in the following optimized code (here a more compact syntax is used to shorten the answer).

```
d = abs(b - a)
if not d: return 6
elif d == 1: return 1 if min(a, b) % n else 0
elif d == n - 1: return 0 if max(a, b) % n else 1
else: return 1 if d == n else 0
```

*Applying steps 2 to 5 above reduces the runtime by another 50%.*

**6. Adjust Order of Conditions based on Input Distribution**

This change relies on the knowledge of the actual input distribution in the application. The target is to make the more frequently seen inputs return faster. In this example, assume the inputs `a` and `b` are uniformly distributed within `[1, n**2]` and `n >= 10`. In this case, the most frequent scenario is that the value `d` does not match any of the `if` conditions and `0` is returned at the end after all conditions are checked. In order to speedup, we can make it fail faster by first checking whether `d` can possibly lead to a non-zero return value.

```
d = abs(a - b)
if 1 < d < n - 1 or d > n: return 0   # Return 0 if d is not in [0, 1, n - 1, n]
elif d == 1: return 1 if min(a, b) % n else 0
elif d == n - 1: return 0 if max(a, b) % n else 1
else: return 1 if d == n else 6  # d == 0 case is moved to the last "else" since it is least frequently seen
```

**7. Using Lookup Tables**

Further speedup can be achieved by using lookup tables. Here, the values `[0, 1, n - 1, n]` for the first conditional check can be stored to speedup the check. In this case, there are two primary options for this: a set or a length-`n+1` list of boolean values. The former uses less memory while the latter has better performance. Note that **the lookup table should be constructed once outside the function and passed into it**. The code using a boolean list as a lookup is as follows:

```
def func(n, a, b, lookup):
    d = abs(a - b)
    if not (d <= n and lookup[d]): return 0
    ...
```

*Applying steps 6 and 7 (with boolean list lookup) reduces the runtime by another 15%.*

Note that in this example a 2D lookup table (implemented as nested lists or dictionaries) can also be applied using `(min(a, b) % n, d)` as indices. However, under the same assumption of input distribution in step 6, this is slightly slower than a 1D lookup  because of the overhead of one extra level of indexing.

The runtime above is the total time of applying the function to all possible `(a, b)` values within `[1, n**2]` for `n=20`.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will definitely try to implement what you have written.

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary, where the keys are boolean expressions is not going to work the way you hope it does. There is no such thing as a boolean-expression-object that could take the place of the key, only booleans. In the end, boolean expressions evaluate to either `True` or `False`, so at most you could only have two key-value pairs.

I would suggest, however, you make things a bit more readable/pythonic:

```
if a%n == 0 and a != n**2 and b == a + 1:
```

or

```
if all((a%n == 0, a != n**2, b == a + 1)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a list of tuples and loop through it:

```
def e_ha(n, t, a, b, E): 
    checks = [
        (a == b, 6),
        (all(a%n == 0, a != n**2, b == a + 1), 0 ),
        (all((a-1)%n == 0, (a-1) != n**2, b == a - 1), 0),
        (all(a%n == 0, b == a-(n-1)), 1),
        (all(b%n == 0, a == b-(n-1)), 1 ),
        (abs(a-b) == 1, 1),
        (abs(a-b) == n, 1),
        (true, 0)
    ]
    for valid, return_value in checks:
        if valid:
            return return_value
```

Caveat:

1. This is most certainly not faster in any way. Timed it multiple times and it was always slower.
2. It is less readable than the alternative